# separate concatenated string in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server that has data like

```
ID  Name   Des
1    A     Text1, Text2
2    B     Text3, Text4
```

Need to select statement to get data like:

```
ID    Name   Des
1      A     Text1
1      A     Text2
2      B     Text3
2      B     Text4
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - can you give a more detailed example of the data in your table and what your expected outcome shoudl be? Where are the "A" and "B" values coming from in your second statement?

Comment: the first 2 rows in the 2nd table is from the first row of the 1st table, 1st row has value 1 A Text1, Text2, need to split this into 2 rows,row1 (1 A Text1) and row2 (1 A Text2) and so on for the other rows in the ist table

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Split`-function which works also on SQL-Server 2005 (which i'm using):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(250))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Then this query returns your result:

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,  
       Split.Item AS Des
FROM dbo.TableName t
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Split](t.Des, ',') Split
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13344/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: its not working on my table, it only returns the first row like this:1      A     Text1 2      B     Text3 any idea

Comment: @Vikram: Sorry, i haven't noticed that you have commented. As you can see i have used your sample data in [sql-fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13344/1/0) and it returns the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select id,name,substr(Des,0,instr(Des,1)) as des
from TableName
union
select id,name,substr(Des,instr(Des,1)+1) as des
from TableName
```